# How to pass an URL as a query string?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to pass an url to a controller.

```
http://something/index.php/api/http%3A%2F%2Fengadget.com
```

I get 404 Not Found error.

**My route**

```
Route::any("/api/{url}", "ApiController@parse");
```

How do I configure a route or controller to make it work?

Comment: Are you using Laravel 3 or 4?

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::any("/api/(:all)", "ApiController@parse");
```

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#wildcards

You use (:all) to catch the rest of the URI

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. As I mentioned, it's not even hitting the route. I get 404 not found.

Comment: beside that, {url} or {anystringhere} is completely valid as far as I know.

Comment: If you're using Laravel 3, it should be api@parse instead. You used both tags so I'm not sure if you're using L3 or L4.

Answer (score 0):

How about without the / in front of "api"?